# Edits to Events Created via Event Template will not Save

Tags: civievent, repeating-events

I would like to customize the title for an event created from an event template but this occurs for any edits made to the event record.

After I make an edit and go through the Save process (click "Save" or "Save and Done" and then select "Only This Event" and then continue), nothing happens and the changes are not saved.

Any idea on what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: Hi Sarah - may be worth comparing with the behaviour on a demo site eg dmaster.demo.civicrm.org. This has 2 benefits. First it confirms if the problem is something unique to your set up. Second it confirms if the issue may have already been identified and fixed. Hope that helps